# TF30172: You don't have permission

Tags: tfs

I have a tfs server installed, and it allow me to connect, but when try to create a team project, it shows this message.

```
TF30172: You do not have permission to create a new team project.
```

All my permission are currently set, or at at least I think so.

What else can I check?

Comment: Are you a member of the "Project Collection Administrators" group?

Comment: I directly add a windows user and set the permission Create project to allow

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2010, I'm using team foundation 2012 Express installed on a WIN7 Pro machine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a know issue with Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2012.

From [Buck Hodges](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/buck%20hodges/)' blog:

> You must use the Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012 (included in all Visual Studio editions or may be separately downloaded) to create a team project on a TFS 2012 server.  If you use VS 2010, you will get an error about not having permission.  The error message is very misleading, because it’s not a problem with your permissions.

You should to install [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2662296?wa=wsignin1.0) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You Should have the right in Team Project Collection administrator . you have to add yourself in this group.

and after that may be it is also required to add yourself in Contributor group.

kindly check that you have give the rights in Team Project Collection Setting .

not in Team Project Setting.

Answer (score 2):

Having tried a plethora of solutions including many reinstalls, service pack reapplication, hotfixes and the two answers provided by Mak and DaveShaw.

The workaround I used was to create the new team project using Visual Studio 2013. Once I did that I was able to add my solutions to source control. I guess VS 2012 could be used too.

Comment: Yeah this worked for my too. Just created the Team Project with VS 2013 and still can see it on VS 2010.

Comment: I created from VS 2015 and see it in all other versions, thx.